# PHP MySQL Query to Match dynamic field value with other fields dynamic match value condition based

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my database table structure in MySQL - I want to match specific dynamic field values with each other as described below:

```
meta_id post_id     meta_key            meta_value
616     472         "machine_type"      "Combined pipe cutting"
561     472         _edit_lock          1354882015:1
560     472         _edit_last          1
562     472         _mf_write_panel_id  1
565     472         _wp_page_template   machine_layout.php
617     472         jet_filter          
618     472         "length_x_axis"     "3000mm"
619     472         machine_image       488
```

Above I have `""` quote marked the fields - against which I have to apply the query and fetch result.

Now here, I want to check `meta_key` field and `meta_value` field and want to retrieve the matching `post_id` field's value.

For ex: my first parameter on `meta_key` will be `length_x_axis` and its matching value in `meta_value` will be `3000mm` and `AND` condition with it will be `meta_key` for `machine_type` and its matching value in `meta_value` will be `Combined pipe cutting`.

And the result I need is `post_id` value `472`

This is a complete dynamic wordpress `wp_postmeta` table which will have many records with conditions like this.

Earliest MySQL Query in result will be appreciated.

Please forgive me if any spell mistakes, I have tried my best to explain the community my question.

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want, but i think that is the query you are looking for:

```
SELECT t1.post_id 
FROM mytable t1 inner join mytable t2 on t1.post_id = t2.post_id 
WHERE t1.meta_key = "length_x_axis" and t1.meta_value="3000mm" 
AND t2.meta_key="machine_type" and t2.meta_value="Combined pipe cutting"
```